# Unable to open an .xlsx file with script in Selenium WebDriver - getting InvalidFormatException

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, excel, assert

I have a script that requires an excel spreadsheet to be downloaded from a website and opened, ending in an assertion that a certain value exists or not on the spreadsheet.

Getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13] at Assert.fail(Assert.java:95)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is now possible in LibreOffice Calc to drive Python Requests and Selenium, no need for Excel anymore...
You must install the [OAuth2OOo](https://prrvchr.github.io/OAuth2OOo/) extension. Enjoy.... More informations: - [Driving Firefox with Calc formulas](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=110202) - [New Calc AddIns for HTML Microdata](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=538997#p538997) Disclaimer: I am the developer of the CalcAddIns.

Answer (score 1):

Use file extension to handle WorkSheet Type

```
String inputFilename = new File(path).getName();

switch (inputFilename.substring(inputFilename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
   inputFilename.length())) {
      case "xls":
      return readXLS(path);

      case "xlsx":
      return readXLSX(path);
      default:
      Log.e(TAG, "No XLS file chosen");
      return "Please select valid \"Excel\" File\"";
}
```

For XLSX file: use XSSFWorkbook & XSSFSheet

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

For XLS file: use HSSFWorkbook & HSSFSheet

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878743/package-should-contain-a-content-type-part-m1-13) for a more detail

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when your create your XLS/XLSX file through LibreOffice. Apparently something is lost in the conversion and the file is not the same as a spreadsheet made in Microsoft Office. I had the same error and the solution for me was copying all the work I have done in LibreOffice Calc to a MS Excel spreadsheet and then save a new file.